# Checar qual o background-image de um elemento

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para checar se algum elemento tem um determinado background com Javascript puro (sem jQuery).

Com jQuery eu consigo usar isto:

```
if( $('.icon').css('background-image') === 'url(http://i56.servimg.com/u/f56/12/05/75/97/e410.png)' ){
    //do something
}
```

Mas estou com dificuldade para fazer via Javascript puro. (lembrando que existem vários elementos `.icon` na página, gostaria que o código só tivesse efeito caso ele tenha aquele background especifico...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em javascript, por enquanto, tem de usar um ciclo `for` e o [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

```
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
var imagem = 'url(http://i56.servimg.com/u/f56/12/05/75/97/e410.png)';
for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
    var este = window.getComputedStyle(icons[i]).backgroundImage;
    if (este == imagem) {
        // fazer algo
        console.log('Tem imagem!');
    }
}
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/7zrk3/**

Este código em cima vai correr o if a cada elementto. Se quiser correr somente se *todos* os elementos timerem essa imagen, então tem de criar uma flag. Por exemplo:

```
var todos = true;
var icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon');
var imagem = 'url(http://i56.servimg.com/u/f56/12/05/75/97/e410.png)';
for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
    var este = window.getComputedStyle(icons[i]).backgroundImage;
    if (este == imagem) flag = false;
}
if (todos){
    // aqui sim pode correr o seu código
}
```

Comment: Só para complementar: `querySelectorAll` só funciona a partir do IE8 ([conforme documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)) e `getComputedStyle` só a partir do IE9 ([documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)).